# Can't use Selenium on a Java server

Tags: java, selenium

I tried making a discord patchbot in java (Data is on a dynamic website).
While the application works in eclipse and as a .jar on my desktop, I can't get it to work properly on the server.
The server is a java-server from sparkedhost.

On every start the following error occurs:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:61)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: It must be an executable file: /home/container/botFiles/chromedriver.exe
        at org.openqa.selenium.internal.Require.stateCondition(Require.java:169)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.checkExecutable(DriverService.java:148)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.findExecutable(DriverService.java:142)
        at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.access$000(ChromeDriverService.java:38)
        at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService$Builder.findDefaultExecutable(ChromeDriverService.java:231)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:437)
        at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.createDefaultService(ChromeDriverService.java:127)
        at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:48)
        at selenium.SeleniumApplicaton.run(SeleniumApplicaton.java:40)
        at main.WebScraper.getNews(WebScraper.java:31)
        at main.DiscordBot.<init>(DiscordBot.java:60)
        at main.DiscordBot.main(DiscordBot.java:27)
        ... 5 more
```

Comment: _"It must be an executable file: /home/container/botFiles/chromedriver.exe"_ - The executable you are trying to run (`chromedriver.exe`) looks like a Windows executable file. But the server you are running it on does not - it starts with a root directory of `/`, suggesting a Linux box. Based on that guess, I think you may need to pick the chromedriver which [matches your server operating system](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=102.0.5005.27/).

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the error message in the stack trace:

> It must be an executable file: /home/container/botFiles/chromedriver.exe

The executable you are trying to run (`chromedriver.exe`) looks like a Windows executable file. But the server you are running it on does not - it starts with a root directory of `/`, suggesting a Linux box.

Based on that, I think you may need to pick the chromedriver which [matches your server operating system](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=102.0.5005.27/).

---

<sup>My guess in the question's comments is converted to an answer, since that turned out to be the solution.</sup>